# Calling 32 bits com out-of-proc server from 64 bits application

Tags: c++, com

I’m porting c++/cli 32 bits application to 64 bits (Windows 7).
Application calls 32 bits out-of-proc server:

```
CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

IDataConvert* pIDataConvert;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_DataConvert, NULL, 
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            IID_IDataConvert, (void**)&pIDataConvert);
```

Works fine as 32 bits client on 64 bits system.
With 64 bits, hr returned is 0x80040154 (Class not registered).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That interface is implemented by oledb32.dll, that is not an out-of-process server.  It works fine with CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER.

Comment: CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER. What do you mean? The goal is to make communicate 64 bits process with 32 bits com server (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER). The problem seems to be in registry

Comment: Sure, no doubt, it isn't supposed to work in 32-bit mode.  Ask an experienced colleague or look through the source code for the installer about a hack that enables a surrogate.

Comment: I found solution. One have to compile proxy stub dll with x64 compiler then register it. In fact with 64 bits system there are 2 regsvr32 (for 32 and 64 bits dlls). As to server executable (.exe) there is nothing to do, it will be called as 32 bits process.